# Using tikz q-tree with an embedded macro

Tags: macros, tikz-trees, linguistics, tikz-qtree

I am trying to create a macro which will create a tree which represents a given phrase. I've seen the explanations for \expandafter and have used it here, but when I embed this macro "\phrase" command within another \phrase command, then the result is that embedded command is read as the text within a node, rather than the continuation of multiple nodes in the \Tree.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\xbar}{$'$}
\newcommand{\phrase}[4]{[.{#1P} {#2} [.{#1\xbar} [.{#1} {#3} ] {#4} ] ]}

\begin{document}

\expandafter    \Tree       \phrase{C}{spec}{head}{comp}

\expandafter    \Tree       \phrase{C}{spec}{head}{\phrase{I}{spec}{head}{comp}}

\end{document}
```

How do I get around this, not just for one embedding, but for as many successive embeddings as I may choose to use (and in any node, not just the "complement" position)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible way. You need to be careful with the braces. I removed them around `#2` and `#4` in order to not confuse the parser. Other than that I first expand the nested `\phrase` in a macro `\temp`, which gets used in the way you do in the case of the unnested `\phrase`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\xbar}{$'$}
\newcommand{\phrase}[4]{[.{#1P} #2 [.{#1\xbar} [.{#1} {#3} ] #4 ] ]}

\begin{document}


\expandafter\Tree\phrase{C}{spec}{head}{{comp}}

\edef\temp{\phrase{I}{spec}{head}{\phrase{C}{spec}{head}{comp}}}
\expandafter\Tree\temp


\edef\temp{\phrase{I}{\phrase{C}{spec}{head}{comp}}{head}{comp}}
\expandafter\Tree\temp

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This doesn't seem to work when I embed the command in the "spec" position / as the second argument rather than the fourth. Is there some way to fix this, and also formalize this in a macro/new environment so that it isn't cluttered? Or do \edef and \temp not work like that?

Comment: @Jackirab As I said, you need to be careful with the braces. What concretely do you want to do? (I added something for `#2`).